# Finding Data with cheerio inside clases

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Im trying to scrape a webpage but im unable to scrape a certain part that is inside an `<ul>` then a `<li>` then a b. So far I have tried these lines of code with no luck:

```
const totalSurfaceHelper = $('.section-icon-features').find('.icon-feature').find('.icon-f icon-f-stotal');
            dwelling.TotalSurface = totalSurfaceHelper.find('b').text();

dwelling.totalSurface = $('.icon-f icon-f-stotal .icon-feature > b').text();
```

[image: I need to get the 214m2 value]

Comment: You missed a dot i.e `.` the expected code should be `dwelling.totalSurface = $('.icon-f .icon-f-stotal .icon-feature > b').text();` I think

Comment: Still getting empty

Comment: No it's: `.icon-f-stotal + br + b`

Comment: If that selector doesn't work, you're probably dealing with a JS-driven page. DevTools can mislead you into thinking that's what Cheerio necessarily sees.